# Python, remove json key

Tags: json

I have 2 API json responses and want to compare if the the data is same or different, however the keys are structure are not identical. Below is an example

```
json1= [
    {
        "Type": "123",
        "entries": {
            "Type": "123",
            "effDate": "2022-07-15",
            "status": "Active",
            "Name": "Delta"
        }
    },
    {
        "Type": "456",
        "entries": {
            "Type": "456",
            "effDate": "2021-11-29",
            "status": "Inactive",
            "Name": "Sigma"
        }
    }
]
```

```
json2= [
    {
        "regionalType": "123",
        "effectiveDate": "2022-07-15",
        "regionalName": "Delta",
        "createdon": "2022-07-15",
        "createdby": "xyz"
    },
    {
        "regionalType": "456",
        "effectiveDate": "2021-11-29",
        "effectiveEndDate": "2021-11-30",
        "regionalName": "Sigma",
        "createdon": "2022-11-29",
        "createdby": "xyz",
        "updatedon": "2021-11-30",
        "updatedby": "xyz"
    }
]
```

Getting error while removing additional key from json2.

new_json_response.remove('effectiveEndDate''samplelastDate')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: Don't convert your structures to JSON until __after__ you're done modifying them. Leave them as native Python data up to and until that point. JSON is an interchange format; you should use it for storing data and sending data, but not for _manipulating_ data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to remove keys

1. convert your new_json_response: `json.loads(new_json_response)`, this will make it to array
2. loop the array, check if `effectiveEndDate` exists, and `del` your `effectiveEndDate` with `del item['effectiveEndDate']`

Comment: Not really.  You can use `x.update(y)` to copy all the keys and values from `y` into `x`, but you pretty much have to delete them by hand.